# sleep until screen updates in java (vsync)

Tags: java

I've been looking on the internet for hours trying to find a good way to make repaint wait until the screen has refreshed before carrying on with the code.

If I have a monitor that updates 60 times per second I don't want the paint code to be running 10000 times per second. I have create this code to try and combat this problem:

```
static int TICKS_PER_SECOND = 20;
static double SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / TICKS_PER_SECOND;
static int MAX_FRAMESKIP = 10;
static int FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 60;
static double SKIP_FRAMES = 1000 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;
static int currentFPS;
static double interpolation;
```

// create main class that extends JPanel and create a JFrame

```
    long sleepTime = 0;
    long next_game_tick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long lastTick = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(processGame){
        short loops = 0;
        while(System.currentTimeMillis() > next_game_tick
                && loops < MAX_FRAMESKIP){
            gameLogic();
            next_game_tick += SKIP_TICKS;
            loops++;
        }
        interpolation = (double) ((System.currentTimeMillis() - next_game_tick + SKIP_TICKS) / SKIP_TICKS);
        game.repaint();
        sleepTime = lastTick - System.currentTimeMillis();

        lastTick += SKIP_FRAMES;

        try{
            if(sleepTime > 1){
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
                System.out.println("Sleeping for " + sleepTime);
            }else{
                Thread.sleep(1);
                System.out.println("Running behind with " + sleepTime);
            }
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

however this code would logicly not properly wait exactly for the screen to update. Is there a way to change Thread.sleep() with something like waitForScreenUpdate() or something?

Comment: Which exactly UI/graphics framework are you using for your application?

Comment: Instead of doing the sleeping yourself, consider using a [ScheduledExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor--).

Comment: His question is how to find out WHEN the screen update happens.